# Load style library into WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

### Long Question:

I downloaded a style library ([Selen.Wpf](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442856/Visual-Studio-Metro-Styles-for-WPF#using)) via NuGet. 
Now I want to use its styles. Frankly, this little task drove me crazy by now.

**First approach - Using MergedDictionarys:**

Ideally I would add the styles as follows

```
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <BitmapImage x:Key="ImgHelp" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Help_32x.png"/>
      <!--Lots of our own stuff goes here too-->
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/Styles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Unfortunaly this throws a runtime excpetion at startup (`System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: "System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage" IsFrozen must be set to false`). This is not the fault of Selen.Wpf, but also happens if I move the declaration of my own Resources from `<Application.Resources>...</Application.Resources>` to `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionarys>...</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionarys>`

The few other questions on SO regarding this problem had no answers, merly workarounds. With no idea how to debug this, I moved on...

**Second approach - Using a Workaround**:

If I get a XamlParseExpcetion doing it the proper way, then just do the ugly code behind hack, I thought.

I added the following function:

```
private void LoadSelen()
{
  ResourceDictionary selenDict = new ResourceDictionary()
  {
    Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/Styles.xaml")
  };

  App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(selenDict);
}
```

and called it between InitComponent and Run

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
  application.InitializeComponent();
  application.LoadSelen();
  application.Run();
}
```

But yet again this lead to a XamlParseExcpetion, but this time in DataPanel.xaml - a panel embedded into my MainWindow:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
HResult=0x80131501
Message = Specifying a value for "System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder" lead to an excpetion.
Source = PresentationFramework
Stacktrace:
 at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)

Inner Excpetion 1:
FileLoadException: The File or Assembly "System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" or a dependency of it was not found. The found manifestdefinition of the assembly does not match the assembly reference (Excpetion of HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Sorry for poor formating, dont know how to do it better. Translated!

DataPanel.xaml where this Excpetion occurs:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GUI.DataPanel"
             x:Name="UserControlPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Background="Transparent">
    <Border  DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=UserControlPanel, Path=HeaderText}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UserControlPanel, Path=Items}" Grid.Column="1">
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
      </Grid>
    </Border>
    <TabControl x:Name="TabControl" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CollapseSingleTabItem}"/>
  </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

---

### Short Question:

How can use the styles from Selen.Wpf. At this point I pretty much don't care how ugly the answer is. As long as it Compiles & Starts (Never thought I would say this outside the C++ world) I am happy.

Comment: Did you try to add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity`?

Comment: Did not before. Tried it now: Unfortunality the problems remain for both methods.

Comment: Is the `FileLoadException` the same?

Comment: After your suggestion failed, I removed the reference afterwards. To check if the `FileLoadExcpetion` is stil the same, I added it again. This time everything worked. Some Buttons were even in the Style of the package. I then removed the Reference (again) to double check. But against all odds it kept working without the ref?

Comment: Restarted VS and cleaned the Soltion - still works. __But this is exactly the same code as posted above__. I don't get it

Comment: Maybe a nuget restore was the only thing needed. Try deleting the the packages folder on the disk to be sure and also remove the `Interactivity` package folder if you added it by nuget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` coudn't be resolved.

> FileLoadException: The File or Assembly "System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" or a dependency of it was not found. The found manifestdefinition of the assembly does not match the assembly reference (Excpetion of HRESULT: 0x80131040)

As it seems the [`Selen.Wpf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selen.Wpf/) nuget package needs this dependency but doesn't specifiy it in the packages description. (You can see that a reference in the [Selen.Wpf.DemoApplication.csproj](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=442856) to it is added)

To resolve this problem you can add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` by yourself (and use your first solution).

Comment: This works indeed. It should be added that you need to reference the right version. It seems that I used 4.0 at first, but Selen needs 4.5. This lead to a lot of confusion on my side, because you can't see the version in VS's projcet explorer. Thanks for helping me out!